# php program getting value from radio in while loop

Tags: php

hi guys im just trying to get the value of selected radio button but it doesnt work help me guys pls. how can i get the selected radio button value tnx in advance :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>asdad</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "POST">

<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('aclc_esys') or die("cannot select DB");
session_start();

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_student_subject WHERE student_id = '".$_SESSION['sess_stud_id']."'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

?>

<input type="radio" name="subj" value="<?php$roww['subject_name']?>">


<?php

echo $row['subject_name']."<br />";
}


?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Evaluation" name="submiteval" />
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submiteval"])){

echo $_POST['subj'];
}


?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled row and you forgot to echo.

Instead of:

```
<?php$roww['subject_name']?>
```

Try:

```
<?php echo $row['subject_name']; ?>
```

Also give at form element an id attribute.

It is very important to use mysqli_* functions not mysql_* ones (they are deprecated) or even better PDO. At least sanitize and validate your inputs so your data will be as valid as you can.

Comment: tnx for ur comment now it works . and i'll follow ur suggestions to use mysqli instead of mysql tnx again ^^